# NixOS: boot to terminal

Tags: linux, nixos

I'm using NixOS with XMonad as a window manager, which was enabled via the configurations.nix. This works fine.

After booting, the initial login is done via the NixOS login gui.

On a Debian system for instance systemd can be configured to boot only to the terminal and not directly to a desktop environment. One can setup an `.xinit` file then to start the chosen window manager or desktop environment without using any display manager (like lightdm, kdm...). It's started then by calling `startx`.

1. How would described effect be done in Nix? I guess there's an
   declarative way to do so.
2. Another question, partly related to this, is: After changing
   xserver settings in the configurations.nix (e.g. in
   services.xserver.synaptics) and rebuilding via `nixos-rebuild
   switch/test`, what do I have to do in order to take them in effect?

Comment: Voting to migrate this to [su]. You'll probably be better off there. :)

Answer (score 1):

Those are 2 separate questions, thus I believe you'd be much better splitting them into 2 StackOverflow questions (it's much harder now to answer e.g. only one of them). That said:

1. AFAIK, people building the NixOS are [not aware of a way to do this in systemd](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/13339). If you know of such method, I believe there might be [interested to learn about it](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/13339)!
2. I suppose you want:

   ```
   $ systemctl start display-manager.service   # CAUTION: see NOTE below!!!
   ```

   **NOTE: this will kill any open X session!** (I guess that this might be the reason why it's not done automatically on *nixos-rebuild switch*...)

   By the way, you may have noticed that after *nixos-rebuild switch*, a message is shown, something like: "display-manager.service is not restarted". That's what led me to find the answer to this question when I needed it myself.

Comment: ``systemctl start display-manager.service`` → The point of the question is to get the display manager out of the way. That’s what ``startx`` is for: a way to launch X on the current console, using the current login session.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to enable `startx`, [which will be treated as a display manager](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Using_X_without_a_Display_Manager):

```
services.xserver.displayManager.startx.enable = true;
```

Another way to accomplish this is to bypass the display manager by logging in automatically from the TTY login prompt. NixOS default display manager being `lightdm`, you do that by adding the following lines to your configuration:

```
lightdm = {
  enable = true;
  autoLogin.enable = true;
  autoLogin.user = "username";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent NixOS from automatically starting the X server (and consequently launching into the GUI) by setting the following in your `configuration.nix`:

```
services.xserver.autorun = false;
```

The change will take effect immediately upon running `nixos-rebuild switch`.

To start the X server manually, run as root:

```
systemctl start display-manager.service
```

To exit the GUI, open a console and stop the display manager service:

```
systemctl stop display-manager.service
```

Source: [NixOS manual](https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/index.html#sec-x11)